# allow viewing unpublished nodes

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, user-permissions

I am running a Drupal 7 site, and I need to allow users to view unpublished nodes, I did check the "Bypass content access control" in permissions page for both authenticated and anonymous users, but instead of "Access denied" I keep getting "The page isn't redirecting properly", while debugging the site with NetBeans, I did notice it goes into infinite loop when visiting that URL.

Any modules/hooks you suggest me using, that'll be great.

Answer (score 2):

The module [views unpublished](https://drupal.org/project/view_unpublished) allows you to grant access for specific user roles to view unpublished nodes of a specific type. Access control is quite granular in this regard. Additionally, using this module does not require any modifications to your existing URL structure.